# How to emit a list separated by commas in YAML

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I have a 9 3x3 matrix of all zeroes. I am trying to output it in row major form so that it will look like.
covariance: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

I have tried

```
out1 << YAML::Key << "covariance";
out1 << YAML::Literal<< covariance[0][0]<< "," << covariance[0][1]... etc.
```

But i get :

covariance: 0
",": 0
what am I doing wrong?

note: I DO NOT want [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. I would like it without the brackets

Comment: `[0,0,0,0]` without the brackets isn't even valid YAML is it? So how can you want it?

Comment: It is according to this http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: (replaced my earlier comment). On yamllint, it interprets `covariance: 1, 2, 3` as `covariance: "1, 2, 3"`, and it interprets `covariance: 1,2,3` as `covariance: 123`. Which suggests the whitespace is important [ I'm new to YAML :-) ]. @Ariel, do you expect spaces after the commas in your output?

Comment: Yah I did notice, that if you do not include spaces in the string after the comma, you get a very different result. i.e. 123 instead of 1,2,3. I guess best practice would be to use a sequence. However I'm just trying to be consistent with my colleagues.

Comment: Are your colleagues expecting to be able to read this with a standard YAML reader? If so, then you might need to think carefully about this. Let's not forget that covariances are real numbers, and therefore you probably expect to be able to do something like `covariance: 0.1,0.2,0.3`. However, that is (as far as I can tell) that is invalid YAML. Do you want to be consistent with your colleagues, or with YAML? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a string up, and then print it out:

```
std::stringstream value;
for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
  value << covariance[0][i];
  if (i + 1 < N) {
    value << ",";
  }
}
YAML::Emitter out;
out << YAML::BeginMap;
out << YAML::Key << "covariance" << YAML::Value << value.str();
out << YAML::EndMap;
```

The point is that the value you're printing isn't a YAML list, it's just a plain string that happens to look a little bit like YAML. So you can't use
yaml-cpp to format it for you; you need to do that yourself.

Comment: Is it true that `covariance: 1, 2, 3, 4` is not a valid YAML document? If so, it might be useful to confirm that explicitly in the answer for those of us not very familiar with YAML

Comment: @AaronMcDaid `covariance: 1, 2, 3, 4` is a valid YAML document; but it's a map with key `covariance` and value `1, 2, 3, 4`, both of which are scalars. The point is, the value is a scalar, not a sequence.

Comment: Your current answer would output `covariance: 1,2,3,4`; i.e. without spaces. My experiments with yamllint suggest that YAML readers would then ignore the commas in that output and read it as a scalar `1234`. Perhaps yamllint isn't correct, but this suggests you should add a space after each comma

Comment: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=covariance%3A+1%2C2%2C3%2C4&type=json reads it as a scalar. This is the correct interpretation.

Comment: That page doesn't even accept numbers in scientific notation, converting them to quoted strings.  ... I'll never understand YAML, even though I keep wanting to :-) :-)

Comment: YAML doesn't require converting anything to a number. All it really requires are maps, sequences, and scalars.

Comment: So you're saying there is no difference between `!!str "3.14"` and `!!float 3.14`? And if those two are different in YAML, then is there a policy that plain `3.14` should be interpreted as one of those two?

Comment: There is a difference: one has the tag `!!str` and the other `!!float`. It's up to the application to determine the interpretation of those.